# Setting linewidth of Pandas boxplot fliers

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, boxplot

As always, I'm amazed by the richness of Pandas's features, as I discover `DataFrame.boxplot`.

But I'd like to be able to manipulate the resulting plot in arbitrary ways (examples include setting the line width, colour and alpha of the 'fliers').

I understand this can be done with `matplotlib.artist.setp` but there's clearly something I don't understand about how `pd.DataFrame.boxplot()` works.

Here's my attempt at doing arbitrary adjustment of the 'fliers':

```
from matplotlib.artist import setp
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[-1, 3, 5], 'bar':[10,-10,15]})
plot = df.boxplot(sym='o')
# Set the linewidth
setp(plot['fliers'], linewidth=3)
draw()
```

Does this look like the right thing to be doing? The linewidth command doesn't seem to do anything. Am I right in thinking that the draw() command redraws the current plot?

Comment: Just want to chime in an say that I've submitted PR to matplotlib to allow full boxplot customization https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2643

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html):

> Flier points are those past the end of the whiskers.

Are you talking about flier points of whiskers?

```
setp(plot['whiskers'], linewidth=3)
```